# Canvas half circle bug workaround in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, geometric-arc

It looks like someone did mention this bug to the Chromium forums but there was no resolution so I'm wondering if anyone simply knows a workaround.

The issue is trying to render a half circle counter-clockwise in Chrome, using the canvas element. Instead this renders a full circle:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('can').getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50,50,50,0,Math.PI*3,true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

Here is a fiddle, view in non-chrome, then in chrome: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45nAW/)

Comment: Half a circle counter-clockwise is from `0` to `Math.PI` unless I'm misunderstanding your question. You're currently drawing one full circle and another half, effectively drawing a full one.

Comment: A good workaround might be try using `Math.PI` instead of `Math.PI*3` - it's hacky, I know, but it gets around those darned high school geometry bugs.

Comment: @pimvdb: No, not with the canvas going counter-clockwise. All browsers render half circle in this case but Chrome

Comment: The idea here isnt to start from angle 0 and travel Math.PI*3, its to start at angle 0 and stop at the point that equates to Math.PI*3, that is how the canvas arc method works.

Comment: I get expected results here: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/220/. What does your expected circle look like?

Comment: Yes, if you notice in chrome, pi*3 drawing shows full circle (when counter-clockwise), while in non-chrome it shows half circle (when counter-clockwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug probably stems from [this part of the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-arc):

> If the anticlockwise argument is omitted or false and
>   endAngle-startAngle is equal to or greater than 2π, or, if the
>   anticlockwise argument is true and startAngle-endAngle is equal to or
>   greater than 2π, then the arc is the whole circumference of this
>   circle.

Chrome does not appear to respect the second part of that statement (i.e. when `anticlockwise` is `true`).

Why not normalize your end-point?

```
var end = 3 * Math.PI;
while (end > 2 * Math.PI) {
    end -= 2 * Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I remember searching around and seeing that and thought it possibly could do with that. Thanks for your help I think this code snippet will fit what I'm trying to do very well.

Comment: Just a note that this is fixed in Version 31.0.1650.63 of Chrome (and probably many version before that)